# how to unzip all files in sub directories

Tags: exec

I  try to extract all files in  all sub directories   by  this command

```
 $ find -name "*.bz2" -print  -exec bizp2 -d "*.bz2" {}\;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

but it doesnot work :(

btw I do not understand  the usage of {};

Comment: your command `bizp2` what should it do? Is that related to `bzip2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your command:

- leave out the "*bz2" option to bzip2, the {} will be replaced by any file find returns
- add a space between {} and \;

so the full command would be

```
 find -name "*bz2" -print -exec bzip2 -d {} \;
```

Comment: it works   , thaaaanks a lot (Y)

Comment: Perfect. All working!

Answer (score 0):

... I don't understand your command...
I would just have used :

```
 find -name *.bz2 -exec bzip2 -d '{}'  ';'
```

I don't understand why you put "*.bz2". According to

```
 man find
```

you should put the thing in quotes '' because the {} could get interpreted by the shell.
With a bit of testing, I think I can conclude the problem lies with the fact that you put no space between {} and \; whereas the man page specifies that the last argument should consist solely of ; .